# how do I minimize a fragment from whole screen to just bottom of my screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-animation

I need to minimize my fragment from whole screen to fit just a small area to the bottom of my screen,just like in google play music .here is the image

[image]

also when downward swipe is initiated it starts to go downwards,I want to have just like that.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at using a [bottom sheet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior.html)

Comment: my minimum sdk is 16.Will it work?

Comment: It is part of the design support library, so it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this github project may help you.

[AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)

or

[Android Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thts depand on your Layout. if you use Relative layout simply use

```html
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

in your view in the xml.
if you will post your xml code I will be able to be more specific.

Comment: Oh I just show the "downward swipe", you want it to animate and go down when the user swipe bottum? or you want him to drag it bottum?
"minimize my fragment from whole screen to fit just a small area to the bottom of my screen" - in the picture the fragment remain in the same size, to waht do you mean minimize?